# Question about about splitted Linked list

Tags: c, algorithm, pointers, linked-list, singly-linked-list

I've got this question where I'm supposed to write a function called - "createList" that gets a linked list(without a dummy element) of ints. The function should remove every element that is bigger than the previous one and the next one.
Also, I have to make a new linked list (without a dummy element) where I place all the removed elements from the original linked list. (The elements should stay in the same order that they appeared in the original linked list).
(createlist is createListEx4() in my code)

For instance, an original linked list : 3->6->1->9->8->4->5;

would be updated to : 3->1->8->4;

The "removed elements" linked list would be: 6->9->5;

**The function will return a pointer to the "removed elements" linked list**

I wrote this code and I cant seem to understand how to make it work.
There is a memory leak while I print the "removed elements" linked list, and doesn't return the correct elements.

```
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>


typedef int data_type;

typedef struct Node2
{
    data_type data;
    struct Node2 *next;
}Node2;

Node2 * createList2(data_type data);
Node2 * addToFirst2(Node2 *head, data_type data);
Node2 * addToLast2(Node2 *head, data_type data);
void printf_List2(Node2 *head);
void Free_List2(Node2 *head);
Node2* createListEx4(Node2 *);
void Insert_To_Big(Node2 **, int);
void delete_item(Node2 **, Node2 **);
Node2* insert_list();

void main()
{
    Node2 *head = NULL;
    Node2 *Odd_list = NULL;
    head = insert_list(); // A Function which creates a Linked List
    printf("You Entered This linked-list:\n");
    printf_List2(head); // A Function which prints the Imported List
    Odd_list = createListEx4(head); // a Function which Returns The address to The Odd linked list
    printf("The Odd Linked-List is:\n");
    printf_List2(Odd_list);  // A Function Which Prints the Odd List
    Free_List2(Odd_list); // Free The list After we have finished using it
}

Node2* insert_list() // A function Which imports numbers to the linked list till -1
{
    int Num;
    Node2 *Head = NULL;
    printf("Please enter the Number you  want to Sort untill -1:\n");
    scanf("%d", &Num);
    while (Num != -1)
    {
        Head = addToLast2(Head, Num); // The last entered Number will be the Head
        scanf("%d", &Num);
    }
    return Head;
}

Node2* createListEx4(Node2 *head) // **head will be in the end the Even Linked List**
{
    Node2 *Big = NULL;
    Node2 *temp, *step, *prev = NULL;
    if (head == NULL) // if the linked list is empty
        return NULL;
    if (head->data > head->next->data)
    {
        Insert_To_Big(&Big, head->data);
        temp = head;
        head = head->next;
        free(temp);
    }
    prev = head;
    // At this point we start runnig the list from an even Number //
    step = head; 
    while (step ->next ->next != NULL)  
    {
        if ((step->data < step->next->data) && (step->next->data > step->next->next->data))
        {
            Insert_To_Big(&Big, step->next->data);
            delete_item(&step, &prev);
        }
        else
        {
            prev = step;         
            step = step->next;
        }
    }
    if (step->data < step->next->data)
    {
        Insert_To_Big(&Big, step->next->data);
        free(step->next);
    }
    step = NULL;
    printf("The Even Linked-List is:\n");
    printf_List2(head); 
    Free_List2(head); 
    return Big;
}

void delete_item(Node2 **step, Node2 **prev) //A Funtions Which Deletes a Node and Connects the prev Node to the Next one
{   
    Node2 *temp = *step; 
    *step = (*step)->next;
    (*prev)->next = *step;
    free(temp); 
}

void Insert_To_Big(Node2 **head, int Num) // A Function Which Creates The Odd linked list
{
    *head = addToLast2(*head, Num);
}


Node2 * createList2(data_type data)
{
    Node2 *temp = (Node2*)malloc(sizeof(Node2));
    temp->data = data;
    temp->next = NULL;
    return temp;
}
Node2 * addToFirst2(Node2 *head, data_type data)
{
    Node2 *temp = createList2(data);
    temp->next = head;
    return temp;
}
Node2 * addToLast2(Node2 *head, data_type data)
{
    Node2 *p = head;
    Node2 *temp = createList2(data);
    if (head == NULL)
        return temp;
    while (p->next != NULL)
        p = p->next;
    p->next = temp;
    return head;
}
void printf_List2(Node2 *head)
{
    Node2 *p = head;
    while (p != NULL)
    {
        printf("%d, ", p->data);
        p = p->next;
    }
    printf("\n\n");
}

void Free_List2(Node2 *head)
{
    Node2 *temp = head;
    while (temp != NULL)
    {
        head = head->next;
        free(temp);
        temp = head;
    }
}
```

Comment: What is this code? What happens when you compile/run it? Why is that wrong? It's not a clear enough problem statement to say "I cant seem to understand how to make it work."

Comment: I guess `createListEx4` is the function that is supposed to do what you described as `createList` in the question?

Comment: I don't think you are supposed to create new nodes, just move some nodes from the original list to the new list. The head node should not move because it has no previous node, so only the second node onward (up to the penultimate node) may be moved to the new list.

Comment: How is that memory leak reported, with what message? If it "doesn't return the correct elements", what _does_ it return?

Comment: In your example, the 5 is moved to the "removed elements" list even though it is at the end of the list. So is the requirement as follows: "For each element on the list: IF element is not at the start of the list AND element is bigger than previous element AND (element is at the end of the list OR element is bigger than next element) THEN remove element"?

Comment: @underscore_d Exeption thrown: read access violation p was 0xDDDDDDDD.
and in the console window it prints it in the following order: 9->5; while the "removed elements'' are: 6->-572662307...

Comment: @ianAbbot The requirement is: If the element at the head is bigger then the next element- move the element to the "removed elements". IF the element at the end of the list is bigger then the previous - move the element to the "removed elements".
IF the element is in the middle (somewhere between the head and the end but not them) is bigger then the prev element and the next element - move the element to the "removed elements"

Comment: @Pasha Grobov I have not understood why 5 was removed. Can you explain? At least the node with the value 5 does not have a next node with a value.

Comment: @Vlad from Moscow  The requirement is: If the element at the head is bigger then the next element- move the element to the "removed elements". IF the element at the end of the list is bigger then the previous - move the element to the "removed elements". IF the element is in the middle (somewhere between the head and the end but not them) is bigger then the prev element and the next element - move the element to the "removed elements"

Comment: @PashaGrobov If the element at the head can be moved then you will need to change the parameter to be a pointer to the pointer to the head of the list, so that the caller's head pointer can be changed to point to a different element if necessary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My five cents.:)

Here is a demonstrative program. I named the corresponding function `split`. The function is called for different corner cases.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct Node
{
    int data;
    struct Node *next;
} Node;

void clear( Node **head )
{
    while ( *head )
    {
        Node *tmp = *head;
        *head = ( *head )->next;
        free( tmp );
    }
}

size_t assign( Node **head, const int a[], size_t n )
{
    clear( head );
    
    size_t count;
    
    for ( size_t i = 0; i < n && ( *head  = malloc( sizeof( Node ) ) ) != NULL; i++ )
    {
        ( *head )->data = a[i];
        ( *head )->next = NULL;
        head = &( *head )->next;
        ++count;
    }
    
    return count;
}

FILE * display( const Node *head, FILE *fp )
{
    for ( ; head != NULL; head = head->next )
    {
        fprintf( fp, "%d -> ", head->data );
    }
    
    fputs( "null", fp );
    
    return fp;
}

Node * split( Node **head )
{
    Node *out_head = NULL;
    Node **out_current = &out_head;
    
    for ( Node *prev = NULL; *head != NULL; )
    {
        if ( prev != NULL || ( *head )->next != NULL )
        {
            if ( ( prev == NULL || prev->data < ( *head )->data ) &&
                 ( ( *head )->next == NULL || ( *head )->next->data < ( *head )->data ) )
            {
                Node *tmp = *head;
                *head = ( *head )->next;
                
                tmp->next = NULL;
                *out_current = tmp;
                out_current = &tmp->next;
            }
            else
            {
                prev = *head;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            prev = *head;
        }
        
        if ( *head != NULL ) head = &( *head )->next;
    }
    
    return out_head;
}

int main(void) 
{
    Node *head = NULL;

    int a1[] = { 3 };

    assign( &head, a1, sizeof( a1 ) / sizeof( *a1 ) );
    
    fputc( '\n', display( head, stdout ) );
    
    Node *head2 = split( &head );
    
    fputc( '\n', display( head, stdout ) );
    fputc( '\n', display( head2, stdout ) );
    
    clear( &head2 );
    clear( &head );

    putchar( '\n' );

    int a2[] = { 3, 6 };

    assign( &head, a2, sizeof( a2 ) / sizeof( *a2 ) );
    
    fputc( '\n', display( head, stdout ) );
    
    head2 = split( &head );
    
    fputc( '\n', display( head, stdout ) );
    fputc( '\n', display( head2, stdout ) );
    
    clear( &head2 );
    clear( &head );

    putchar( '\n' );

    int a3[] = { 6, 3 };

    assign( &head, a3, sizeof( a3 ) / sizeof( *a3 ) );
    
    fputc( '\n', display( head, stdout ) );
    
    head2 = split( &head );
    
    fputc( '\n', display( head, stdout ) );
    fputc( '\n', display( head2, stdout ) );
    
    clear( &head2 );
    clear( &head );

    putchar( '\n' );

    int a4[] = { 3, 6, 1, 9, 8, 4, 5 };
    
    assign( &head, a4, sizeof( a4 ) / sizeof( *a4 ) );
    
    fputc( '\n', display( head, stdout ) );
    
    head2 = split( &head );
    
    fputc( '\n', display( head, stdout ) );
    fputc( '\n', display( head2, stdout ) );
    
    clear( &head2 );
    clear( &head );
    
    return 0;
}
```

The program output is

```
3 -> null
3 -> null
null

3 -> 6 -> null
3 -> null
6 -> null

6 -> 3 -> null
3 -> null
6 -> null

3 -> 6 -> 1 -> 9 -> 8 -> 4 -> 5 -> null
3 -> 1 -> 8 -> 4 -> null
6 -> 9 -> 5 -> null
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code is much more complicated than need and also contains a number of logical errors.

For instance, you shouldn't use `malloc` and `free` when moving node from one list to the other. Just change pointers.

And this part from the start of `createListEx4`

```
if (head->data > head->next->data)
{
    Insert_To_Big(&Big, head->data);
    temp = head;
    head = head->next;
    free(temp);
}
```

You only compare `head` to `head->next` but that's not what your requirements are saying. Further, you simply `free` the element but it should have been moved - not `free`d.

Below is an implementation you can look at. There are room for improvements but I tried to keep the code simple so that it's easy to understand.

```
typedef int data_type;

typedef struct node
{
    data_type data;
    struct node *next;
} node;


node* create_static_list(void)
{
  // Bypassing check for NULL for readability - don't do it in real code
  node* r = NULL;
  int a[] = {5, 4, 8, 9, 1, 6, 3};
  for (size_t i = 0; i < sizeof a / sizeof a[0]; ++i)
  {
    node* t = malloc(sizeof *t);
    t->next = r;
    t->data = a[i];
    r = t;
  }
  return r;
}

void add_to_other_list(node** head, node* p)
{
  static node* tail = NULL;

  p->next = NULL;
  if (tail == NULL)
  {
    *head = p;
  }
  else
  {
    tail->next = p;
  }
  tail = p;
}

node* remove_special(node* p)
{
  node* res = NULL;

  if (p == NULL) return res;          // 0 elements
  if (p->next == NULL) return res;    // 1 element
  if (p->next->next == NULL)          // 2 elements
  {
    // Special handling of last element in list
    if (p->next->data > p->data)
    {
      // Move p->next to other list
      add_to_other_list(&res, p->next);
      p->next = NULL;
      return res;
    }
  }

  // Repeat as long as the list has minimum 3 elements
  while (p->next->next)
  {
    if ((p->next->data > p->data) &&
        (p->next->data > p->next->next->data))
    {
      // Move p-next
      node* t = p->next;
      p->next = p->next->next;
      add_to_other_list(&res, t);
    }
    p = p->next;
  }

  if (p->next == NULL) return res;    // 1 element left, just return

  if (p->next->next == NULL)          // 2 elements left - check last element 
  {
    // Special handling of last element in list
    if (p->next->data > p->data)
    {
      // Move p->next to other list
      add_to_other_list(&res, p->next);
      p->next = NULL;
    }
  }

  return res;
}

// This is OPs function (expect for variable names)
void print_list(node *p)
{
    while (p != NULL)
    {
        printf("%d, ", p->data);
        p = p->next;
    }
    printf("\n\n");
}

int main(void)
{
  node* head = create_static_list();
  print_list(head);
  node* removed = remove_special(head);
  print_list(head);
  print_list(removed);
}
```

**OUTPUT**

```
3, 6, 1, 9, 8, 4, 5,

3, 1, 8, 4,

6, 9, 5,
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to create new elements for the returned list. Elements removed from the original list can be moved to the returned list by manipulating the links.

An element is to be moved from the original list to the returned list if its data is bigger than all of its neighboring elements that exist. There are two special cases to consider: (1) if the original list is empty, the returned list is empty; (2) if the original list consists of a single element, move it to the returned list. (Case (2) was not explicitly stated by OP, but it seems consistent. It only affects the tests for whether an element should be moved or not, which can be changed easily.)

Since the first element can be removed from the original list the function's parameter should be a double pointer, pointing to the link to the first element of the list.

The following function implements the list processing described above:

```
Node2 *createListEx4(Node2 **list)
{
    Node2 *bigHead = NULL;  /* Head of 'big' list. */
    Node2 **bigEnd = &bigHead; /* Pointer to terminating link of 'big' list. */
    Node2 *prev = NULL; /* Previous element to compare data with. */
    Node2 *next;        /* Next element to compare data with. */
    Node2 *cur;         /* Current element. */

    while ((cur = *list) != NULL)
    {
        next = cur->next;
        if ((!prev || cur->data > prev->data) &&
            (!next || cur->data > next->data))
        {
            /* Move current element to 'big' list. */
            *bigEnd = cur;
            bigEnd = &cur->next;
            *list = next;
        }
        else
        {
            /* Skip over current element. */
            list = &cur->next;
        }
        prev = cur;
    }
    /* Terminate the 'big' list. */
    *bigEnd = NULL;
    return bigHead;
}
```

Examples:

Original: (null)
Returned: (null)
Remaining: (null)

Original: 1
Returned: 1
Remaining: (null)

Original: 1 2
Returned: 2
Remaining: 1

Original: 2 1
Returned: 2
Remaining: 1

Original: 1 2 3
Returned: 3
Remaining: 1 2

Original: 1 3 2
Returned: 3
Remaining: 1 2

Original: 2 1 3
Returned: 2 3
Remaining: 1

Original: 2 3 1
Returned: 3
Remaining: 2 1

Original: 3 1 2
Returned: 3 2
Remaining: 1

Original: 3 2 1
Returned: 3
Remaining: 2 1